# Whats the best term to use for approval after a checkbox? "Show" or "Enable"?

Tags: terminology

I am creating a panel, a part of a dashboard and would want to know whats the best term to use. User can disable or enable an specific item by showing it or not. For terminology purposes only, whats the best word to use, "Show" or "Enable".

Example is the image below,

[image]

[ ] Show users a Help Menu Item

or

[ ] Enable Help Menu Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Show panel" in case the panel is getting hidden, for example, slides to hide from user.

"Enable panel" in case the panel is always there, but looks disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear and doesn't provide us with context (when is it used, why, for what etc etc.). But as a rule of thumb: What ever is closer to your users mental model.

As nielson said

> The system should speak the users' language, with words, phrases and concepts familiar to the user, rather than system-oriented terms. Follow real-world conventions, making information appear in a natural and logical order.
>   http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

So probably "Show panel", but it really depends on the context.